# Build Release flutter ios app from windows 10

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

Can I release ipa file from windows?
When I use codemagic, I got an Runner.app. zip file. then how to convert to ipa file. And how to install it on ios.
Is there any easy method

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using a tool named Odevio. Odevio is desktop application can be installe from https://www.odevio.com

Once installed you can setup your Apple Developer Account with Odevio in the Apple section.

You can then start building in the build menu with a Publication build type.

The build is automatically sent to Apple then you just have to submit the build through the Apple Connect interface.

For a more detailed tutorial you can check a full tutorial here : https://odevio-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/5_create_apple_developer_account.html

Answer (score 1):

Use cloud build. https://developer.apple.com/xcode-cloud/
You can build from windows also. You may just have to configure GitHub or gitlab with this and you can directly deploy to test flight

Comment: How can I download xcode on windows. Can I download it directly. Sorry I have no idea about it.

Comment: You don't have to download xcode if you are doing a cloud build

Answer (score 0):

it's not about *converting* `.app` to `.ipa` but about *signing* your application. And to sign iOS application you need [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/) membership.

Also you need one time access to macOS computer to create development certificate - you can ask friends or use Codemagic machine for this (read how to [access build machine](https://docs.codemagic.io/troubleshooting/accessing-builder-machine-via-ssh/)).

Finally with signing certificate issued by Apple and development certificate you can sign and distribute your app using Codemagic - read more here https://ioscodesigning.io/